# Can one toggle inline image show 'at point' in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

I know there's `org-toggle-inline-images` function, is there something like `org-toggle-inline-image-at-point`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no function that's exactly like that.

However if you examine the source code of `org-inline-images`, you'll see the function `org-display-inline-images` which takes `beg` and `end`, the point that begin and end a region, as arguments. In `org-toggle-inline-images`, `beg` and `end` were omitted so they defaulted to the entire buffer. If you were to use `org-display-inline-images` on a region containing only one link, it would do what you want.

To undisplay the images you could just call `org-toggle-inline-images` (it should toggle off because it checks to see if there's any overlays in the global variable `org-inline-image-overlays` and there will be because `org-display-inline-images` adds to this variable).

This is very quick code to do this. I've tested it and it works for me.

```
(defun +org-toggle-inline-image-at-point ()
  "Toggle inline image at point."
  (interactive)
  (if-let* ((bounds (and (not org-inline-image-overlays)
                         (org-in-regexp org-link-any-re nil t)))
            (beg (car bounds))
            (end (cdr bounds)))
      (org-display-inline-images nil nil beg end)
    (org-toggle-inline-images)))
```